# Finding rows with duplicate values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, group-by

I have a one to many relationship between the `Account` table and a `ScheduledPayment` table. One account can have many payments but there should be a maximum of **one** payment per day.
Although unlikely, there are two scenarios which I need to cater for...

1. If there is one or more `Payment` records for an `AccountId` on a
   day, with different payment and or reference then all payments
   should be marked as cancelled.
2. If there is more than one `Payment` record for an `AccountId` on a
   day, with the same payment and reference then one record should be
   the winner and the other be marked as cancelled.

In reality, I don't anticipate seeing this scenario all that much because it is down to a concurrency issue in code, if two users are working on the same record at the same time.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
Account
---------
AccountId
---------
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

```
ScheduledPayment
----------------
ScheduledPaymentId | AccountId | Amount | Reference | State
------------------------------------------------------------
       1           |    1      |  100   | ABCDE     | Live
       2           |    1      |  100   | ABCDE     | Live  (For these two, 1 would the winner and two marked as cancelled)
       3           |    2      |  100   | ABCDE     | Live
       4           |    2      |  110   | ABCDE     | Live
       5           |    2      |  110   | ABCDE     | Live
       6           |    2      |  130   | ABCDE     | Live (For these, all would be marked as cancelled)
       7           |    3      |  100   | ABCDE     | Live
       8           |    4      |  100   | ABCDE     | Live
```

Comment: Sample data for both tables and desired outcome would be really helpful with this question.

Comment: "In reality, I don't anticipate seeing this scenario all that much because it is down to a concurrency issue in code, if two users are working on the same record at the same time." Why not mark the record as locked in the application when the first user retrieves it to prevent a second user updating the record ? Would eliminate part 2

Comment: You should probably put some type of unique index or constraint on the `Payment` table to avoid these types of duplicates.

Comment: If I well understood, part 1 is also subject to more than one payment because you can't have two different values if there is only one, so the two solutions above would both take care of 1 and 2.

Comment: I appreciate that indexes would be the easiest option but if I were to approach this using a query to identify those records, how would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return tag the records that need attention.  I put the tagging in SELECT, but you could easily turn this into a second CTE and simply select out the payments to clean up.

```
-- 
-- find all accounts with more than one payment and mark payments to cancel
--
WITH cte_DuplicatePayments AS
(
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY accountID) AS numberOfPaymentsPerAccountID
, COUNT(*) OVER(partition BY accountID, amount) AS numberOfPaymentsPerAccountIDAndAmount
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition BY accountID ORDER BY amount asc) AS PaymentsNumberPerAccountID
, *
FROM ScheduledPayment
)
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN numberOfPaymentsPerAccountID != numberOfPaymentsPerAccountIDAndAmount THEN 'MARK AS CANCELLED: Duplicate Payments with amount mismatch' 
    WHEN PaymentsNumberPerAccountID > 1 THEN 'MARK AS CANCELLED: Duplicate Payments with matching amount' 
    ELSE ''
   END AS PaymentAuditAction
, ScheduledPaymentID, accountID, amount,
FROM cte_DuplicatePayments
WHERE numberOfPaymentsPerAccountID > 1
```

Comment: A couple of tweaks and this worked exactly!